# Report generator for Cisco call manager

Tags: looking-for-a-script, web-applications

We have an old Cisco call manager at our office and the call manager generates a call history report in `.csv` files everyday. We need to make the call log history report available for managers on web based system.

What tool will help to automatically generate web pages for the `.csv` files when the call manager creates the .csv file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by generating the .csv files, do you mean generate web pages?

Comment: @paulmorriss Yes i want to make a website for the list the of csv file when get from call manager.

Comment: I've changed the question to hopefully make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

A basic PERL, PHP, or Python script would be needed to parse it and display the results for you. If you can't find an existing script for parsing those log files then you would need to write one yourself. Fortunately working with CSV files is easy. If you choose to use PHP they have a lot of [built in functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for parsing CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

You could open the csv file in Excel and save as .html. If you want it done automatically you can do this with VBA:

```
Workbooks.Open ("export.csv")
Workbooks("export.csv").SaveAs "export.html", xlHtml
```